# Close collapse material drawer menu item on new fragment

Tags: android, materialdrawer

Am using  [mike penz](https://github.com/mikepenz/MaterialDrawer) material drawer for my project and its working great except this issue. After visiting a previous fragment which falls under a collapse menu, say for example, **Create New job** as shown in the screenshot, and i go to **Profile**, i want the the collapsed menu for which that item falls under in this case **Jobs** to be closed automatically. Any help is appreciated.
[image: screenshot]

Comment: Did you find any solutions?

Comment: @MahmoudHeretani sorry not yet.

Answer (score 0):

The `MaterialDrawer` library uses the `FastAdapter` as adapter behind the scenes to offer expandable functionality, and additional APIs to simplify the work with the `RecyclerView` showing the elements.

To collapse all expanded items within the drawer, it is possible to access the `expandableExtension` from the `MaterialDrawerSliderView`, and use its API to for example collapse all items.

```
binding.slider.expandableExtension.collapse()
```

To connect this to the `Drawer`, call this for example when the `Profile` item was clicked and you were notified via the `onDrawerItemClickListener`

> The provided sample code is based on the MaterialDrawer v8.x.y version